# R ggplot multiple lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am in the process of creating a plot in R for the below dataset.

```
Date    Type    Count
2016-01 Frm 60
2016-01 Hrd 11
2016-02 Frm 49
2016-02 Hrd 10
2016-03 Frm 67
2016-03 Hrd 9
```

I need to plot a graph with `Date` in `X` axis with 2 different lines spanning across the graph, one each for Type variable based on Count variable. Could you please help how to do this using `ggplot` in R?

Comment: Have a look at the second answer there (highest voted, not accepted).

Comment: type cast df$Type to as.factor(df$Type) and then g + geom_line(color = Type) . g is ggplot(df, aes(x = Date, y = Count).